# NX workspace-generator exception when using directory property

Tags: angular, generator, nrwl-nx

I created an NX `workspace-generator` to create Angular libraries with custom settings.

All works fine and I can generate the library using the `libraryGenerator()` method.

However, if I pass the `--directory` parameter, I get the following exception:

```
Cannot find configuration for 'myLib' in /workspace.json.

The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 
'npx nx workspace-generator ng-library myLib --teamName=myTeam --directory=parentDir --dry-run'" 
terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Any idea why passing the directory property triggers such an error?
I could *move* the library into the parentDir, but I would like to avoid it since specifying a directory inside the given `libraryGenerator()` method seems to be the legit way. I use `"@nrwl/angular": "13.1.5"` and I cannot (for the moment) update to a newer version.

My **index.ts** file:

```
import {
    Tree,
    formatFiles,
    installPackagesTask,
    readProjectConfiguration,
    generateFiles,
    joinPathFragments,
    updateProjectConfiguration,
    getProjects,
    ProjectConfiguration
} from '@nrwl/devkit';
import { libraryGenerator } from '@nrwl/angular/generators';
import { LibSchemaModel } from './lib-schema.model';

export default async function (tree: Tree, schema: LibSchemaModel) {
    const libraryName = schema.name;

    await libraryGenerator(tree, {
        name: libraryName,
        importPath: `@${schema.importPathPrefix}/${libraryName}`,
        publishable: schema.libraryType === 'publishable',
        buildable: schema.libraryType === 'buildable',

        directory: schema.directory // <- If I comment this line, all works fine
    });

...

}
```

My **generator schema.json**:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
    "cli": "nx",
    "$id": "ng-library",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The name of the library.",
            "x-prompt": "Which name do you want to use for the library?",
            "$default": {
                "$source": "argv",
                "index": 0
            }
        },
        "teamName": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The team name.",
            "x-prompt": "Which is the library's team name?"
        },
        "importPathPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The prefix used for the library importPath."
        },
        "directory": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The directory that will contain the new library."
        },
        "libraryType": {
            "description": "Library type: `Publishable` to publish it outside the workspace or `Buildable` to use it internally in the workspace.",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "publishable",
            "enum": [
                "publishable",
                "buildable"
            ],
            "x-prompt": {
                "message": "Which library type do you want to generate?",
                "type": "list",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "value": "publishable",
                        "label": "Publishable"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "buildable",
                        "label": "Buildable"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "installDeps": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "description": "Install dependencies",
            "default": true
        }
    },
    "required": ["name", "teamName", "teamEmail"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are reading the library data with readProjectConfiguration() after library was created with libraryGenerator().

readProjectConfiguration() accepts library/project name as a second argument. However library/project name is NOT equal to schema.name. If the directory was set then your library/project name is equal to `${schema.directory}-${schema.name}`

So in your case the correct code may look like this:

```
export default async function (tree: Tree, schema: LibSchemaModel) {
  const libraryName = schema.directory ? `${schema.directory}-${schema.name}` : schema.name;

  await libraryGenerator(tree, {
      name: schema.name,
      importPath: `@${schema.importPathPrefix}/${libraryName}`,
      publishable: schema.libraryType === 'publishable',
      buildable: schema.libraryType === 'buildable',
      directory: schema.directory
  });

  // When you read the data use libraryName instead of schema.name
  const libConfig = readProjectConfiguration(tree, libraryName);

  // ... do your other stuff
}
```

Comment: Same issue on github https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/11193